# How to do an sortBy with a field and a count(*) on a joined table in Slick 2?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm trying to sort my query by one field and the count of the joined query. That's my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM stmt s 
LEFT JOIN rctn r ON s.id = r.stmt_id 
GROUP BY s.id 
ORDER BY (s.time + INTERVAL 1*COUNT(r.stmt_id) DAY) DESC
```

I already have

```
stmts.where(_.orgid === orgId)
    .innerJoin(rctns).on(_.id === _.stmtId)
    .groupBy(_._1.id)
```

, but I have no idea how to do the sortBy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Very much like in Scala collections:

```
stmts.filter(_.orgid === orgId)
  .innerJoin(rctns).on(_.id === _.stmtId)
  .groupBy(_._1.id)
  .sortBy{ case (s_id,group) =>
    group.map(_._1.time).max + interval(
      group.map(_._2.stmtId).length,
      "DAY"
    )
  }
```

The `.max` is a hack because we currently do not support `.head`, which you would have to use in Scala collections. Be aware, that `interval` does not come with Slick and you will have to define it yourself using the `SimpleExpression` construct, see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/userdefined.html#scala-database-functions.

Notice that in the past we had more bugs with group by in Slick than with other operations. SQL pulls a lot of type-tricks (identifiers changing type between collections and scalar values, etc.), which are tricky to get right in a mapping to Scala semantics. The things we know about are fixed now. If you experience a case where invalid SQL is generated, please report a bug that allows us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thx for the answers. Just another question regarding this: I wrote the interval function `val interval = SimpleFunction.binary[Column[Int], String, Timestamp]("INTERVAL")` and now I'm getting the error `could not find implicit value for parameter tm: scala.slick.ast.BaseTypedType[java.sql.Timestamp] with scala.slick.ast.NumericTypedType  group.map(_._1.time).max + interval(`. I searched for the error, but the docs to slick are very rare. what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: did you import .simple._ from your driver at the place wher it happens?

Comment: yes. `import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._`

Comment: Please report a bug including a code sample that allows us to replicate the problem. e.g. a github project